# Custom UINavigationBar Background

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I've been trying to set up a custom background for the whole of my NavigationBar (not just the titleView) but have been struggling.

I found this thread

http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1649012&tstart=0

But am not sure how to implement the code snippet that is given. Is the code implemented as a new class? Also where do I instatiate the `UINavigationController` as I have an application built with the NavigationView template so it is not done in my root controller as per the example

Comment: another solution http://snipt.net/jonatasmiguel/tag/mac

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You just have to overload drawRect like that :

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (CustomImage)
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"NavigationBar.png"];
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}
@end
```

Comment: Is this the 'recommended' resp. 'valid' way to override this with a category?

Comment: How would one assign the image from the ViewController?  Essentially, how do I extend                                                      - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rec    with    - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rec withImageName:(NSString *)imageName

Comment: This worked for me very well until I used the MPMoviePlayerViewController. Apparently they use a subclassed UINavigationBar so my custom bar was showing up on that. I had to use @ardalahmet's [method below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704558/custom-uinavigationbar-background/4983492#4983492), but added a call to `super` if its not a `UINavigationBar` using `isMemberOfClass:[UINavigationBar class]`

Comment: Overriding methods using a category is not a good idea. At runtime, it is undefined which version of the implementation will be used.

Comment: The problem you have is that if you use a navigation controller, the title of each page will overlay your custom nav bar.  You could set the title to blank, but some views force a title (like the photo picker). To switch nav bars at will, add a property to your app delegate to hold the name of the nav-bar image and replace the first line above with these two:

Comment: Apple specifically recommend against this technique.  You should subclass UINavigationBar and overload drawRect.  Then in your XIB specify your subclass as the class for the UINavigationBar.

Comment: Looks like this method is broken with iOS 5.

Comment: That's because in iOS 5 there are new public API methods for doing this: you need to conditionally code so this only executes on iOS 4 and below

Comment: You should use the [appearance proxy](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006887-CH3-SW23) to do this in iOS 5.0 and later, and subclasses to do it in previous versions. Overriding methods on a category [is strongly discouraged.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5272612/798224)

Comment: since this code you cannot setup the title of your navigation bar

Comment: @IvanVučica it's not broken but you have to make a subclass and have to use in your custom navigation controller. UINavigationBar category won't work with iOS 5

Comment: @AlexMarkman Exactly what I meant. Plus, using appearance proxy, as Phil Calvin suggested, is the right way to go for 99% of customizations.

Answer (score 44):

Uddhav and leflaw are right. This code works nicely:

```
@interface CustomNavigationBar : UINavigationBar
@end

@implementation CustomNavigationBar
-(void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"myNavBarImage"];
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}
@end

// this can go anywhere
+(UINavigationController*) myCustomNavigationController
{
  MyViewController *vc = [[[MyViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
  UINavigationController *nav = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomNavigationController" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
  nav.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:vc];
  return nav;
}
```

You have to create CustomNavigationController.xib and put a UINavigationController in it and change the navigationBar class to "CustomNavigationBar".

Comment: the line:
MyViewController *vc = [[[MyViewController alloc] init]; 
has an extra [. Otherwise, worked very well.

Comment: Thanks. I added in an autorelease call which was supposed to be there.

Comment: How can I change the class of the navigation bar if I create the navigation controller programmatically ?

Comment: This way, can you also change slightly it's height ?

Answer (score 31):

You must use the 'appearance' proxy to change the background and other styling properties of controls such as `UINavigationBar`, `UIToolBar` etc. in iOS 5.xx. However, these are not available for iOS 4.xx so for backwards compatibility, you need a hybrid solution.

If you want to support both iOS 4.xx and iOS 5.xx devices (i.e. your `DeploymentTarget` is 4.xx), you must be careful in wrapping the call to the appearance proxy by checking at runtime if the 'appearance' selector is present or not.

You can do so by:

```
//Customize the look of the UINavBar for iOS5 devices
if ([[UINavigationBar class]respondsToSelector:@selector(appearance)]) {
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NavigationBar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

You should also leave the iOS 4.xx workaround that you may have implemented. If you have implemented the `drawRect` workaround for iOS 4.xx devices, as mentioned by @ludwigschubert, you should leave that in:

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (BackgroundImage)
//This overridden implementation will patch up the NavBar with a custom Image instead of the title
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
     UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"NavigationBar.png"];
     [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}
@end
```

This will get the `NavBar` look the same in both iOS 4 and iOS 5 devices.

Comment: This is the cleanest solution for supporting both iOS 4.xx & 5.xx.

Answer (score 26):

Implementing a category is not advisable. iOS5 may provide relief for this issue. But for old APIs, you can -

1. Subclass `UINavigationBar` to say `CustomNavBar` and implement the custom drawRect from Lithium's answer.
2. For all IB based `UINavigationControllers`, provide `CustomNavBar` as custom class for their `UINavigationBar`.
3. For all code based `UINavigationControllers`. Create a XIB with a `UINavigationController` and do step two. Then provide a factory method in code that loads the `UINavigationController` from the nib and provide an `IBOutlet`.

Eg.

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomNavigationController" owner:self options:nil];
UINavigationController *navController = self.customNavigationController;
navController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:controller]
```

Comment: Excellent, this approach is working for me on iOS 4.2.1 and iOS 5.0.1

Comment: Good answer - please note this also works for getting a view reference out of a xib (no outlets needed) `UINavigationController * navigationController = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomNaviagionController" owner:nil options:nil] lastObject];`

Answer (score 10):

You can also override the `drawLayer:inContext:` method in a `UINavigationBar` category class. Inside the `drawLayer:inContext:` method, you can draw the background image you want to use.

```
- (void) drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
    if ([self isMemberOfClass:[UINavigationBar class]] == NO) {
        return;
    }

    UIImage *image = (self.frame.size.width > 320) ?
                        [UINavigationBar bgImageLandscape] : [UINavigationBar bgImagePortrait];
    CGContextClip(context);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, image.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height), image.CGImage);
}
```

And as a complete demo Xcode project on customizing the appearance of `UINavigationBar` [this](http://www.ardalahmet.com/2011/02/11/ios-development/customizing-the-appearance-of-uinavigationbar/) and [this](https://github.com/ardalahmet/CustomizingNavigationBarBackground) might be helpful.

Comment: Do not do this.  Subclass UINavigationBar and implement drawRect:.  Specify your subclass as the class for the UINavigationBar in your XIBs.

Answer (score 4):

I just found this blog entry, describing this topic very simple: http://web0.at/blog/?p=38

it helped me a lot, they use the "drawRect" method to get the customisation of the background.

Answer (score 4):

Implementing a category won't work in iOS5, you should use Uddhav Kambli's advice for using CustomNavbar on iOS ≤ 5.

Comment: In the iOS 5 beta, the UINavigationBar, UIToolbar, and UITabBar implementations have changed so that the drawRect: method is not called on instances of these classes unless it is implemented in a subclass. Apps that have re-implemented drawRect: in a category on any of these classes will find that the drawRect: method isn't called. UIKit does link-checking to keep the method from being called in apps linked before iOS 5 but does not support this design on iOS 5 or later.

Comment: Thanks for that reply. Do you think this is to encourage people to sub class instead of doing the drawRect globally on all instances using a category?

Comment: This is exactly what I'm thinking about.

Answer (score 3):

To all those who are having trouble with UINavigationBar custom backgrounds in iOS5, do this in the corresponding viewDidLoad methods:

```
#if defined(__IPHONE_5_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_5_0
if ([self.navigationController.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector( setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)]){
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TitleBar"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
#endif
```

Notice that in my case, the background image was named "TitleBar". You can put whatever your custom background image name is.

Comment: for some reason the closing #endif just won't sit inside the code bracket. Sorry for garbled #endif.

Comment: thanks, that is working! And don't forget to create @2x image

Comment: the #define is preprocessor macro. Its useful only during compile. So if you are compiling for iOS5 and later, it will work. If you are compiling for pre-iOS5, the #ifdef will return false and that part of code will not be compiled. The #ifdef is good to have in case you compile your code across multiple iOS versions ,including pre-ios5, mostly to check for any compatibility issues.

Comment: There is no need for static #if #endif wrapper because you are verifying dynamically if the class responds to selector.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you'll have is that if you use a navigation controller, the title of each page will overlay your custom navbar.  If your navbar contains a logo or the name of your app, this is obviously unacceptable.

You could set the title of each view in your navigation stack to blank, but some views force a title that you can't do anything about (like the photo picker). So you might want to create an alternate navbar image with the same color or design as your logo navbar, but with a blank area to make room for overlaid titles.

To switch navbar images at will, add a property to your app delegate to hold the name of the navbar image and replace the first line of the first example above with these two:

```
    YourAppDelegate* theApp = (YourAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:theApp.navBarName];
```

Then in the first view controller that you'll push onto the navigation stack, do something like this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    YourAppDelegate* theApp = (YourAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    theApp.navBarName = @"navBar_plain";
}
```

Then in the root view controller, do the same thing but specify your logo-bearing navbar image, so it gets restored when the user navigates back to it and there is no conflicting title.

Comment: Really good point. Now after you said that, I'm rethinking this now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to Use UINavigationController's delegate. 
It doesn't require subclassing/overwriting the UINavigationBar class:

```
/*
 in the place where you init the navigationController:
 fixer = [[AENavigationControllerDelegate alloc] init];
 navigationController.delegate = fixer;
*/

@interface AENavigationControllerDelegate : NSObject <UINavigationControllerDelegate>
@end

@implementation AENavigationControllerDelegate

#define bgImageTag 143

- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController 
   didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController 
                animated:(BOOL)animated
{
     //this is for the future for implementing with the appearance api:

    if ([[navigationController navigationBar] respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)])
    {
        static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
        dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
            [[navigationController navigationBar] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"header-logo-bg.png"]
                                                   forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
        });
 }
    else
        {
        UIImageView* imageView = (UIImageView*)[navigationController.navigationBar viewWithTag:bgImageTag];
        if(!imageView)
        {
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"header-logo-bg.png"];
            imageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image] autorelease];
            imageView.tag = bgImageTag;
        }

        [navigationController.navigationBar insertSubview:imageView atIndex:0];        
    }
}

@end
```

https://gist.github.com/1184147

Answer (score 2):

In iOS5, `zPosition` value (of `UINavigationBar's` most depth layer) is changed. So if you change that `zPosition`, the old way works.

eg.

```
UINavigationBar *_bar = navigationController.navigationBar;

// Insert ImageView    
UIImage *_img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navibar.png"];
UIImageView *_imgv = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:_img] autorelease];
_imgv.frame = _bar.bounds;

UIView *v = [[_bar subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
v.layer.zPosition = -FLT_MAX;

_imgv.layer.zPosition = -FLT_MAX+1;
[_bar insertSubview:_imgv atIndex:1];
```

This script handle view's layer, so You should import `QuartzCore`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative solution that lets you use your own custom subclass of UINavigationBar:

https://gist.github.com/1253807

Answer (score 1):

As Apple itself has said, it is not correct to override methods in Categories. So the best way to customize the background of `UINavigarionBar` is subclassing and override `-(void)drawInRect:` method.

```
@implementation AppNavigationBar
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIImage *patternImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image_name.png"];
    [patternImage drawInRect:rect];
}
```

To use this customized `UINavigationBar` it should be set as `navigationBar` property of your `UINavigationBarController`. As you know this property is readonly. So what should be done is:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    AppNavigationBar *nav = [AppNavigationBar new];
    [self setValue:nav forKey:@"navigationBar"];
}
```

It works for both iOS 5 and 4.3.

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass UINavigationBar and enable it like this, since categories for drawRect won't work in iOS5 anymore

```
    navigationController = [[((^ {
    NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:navigationController]];
    [unarchiver setClass:[SAPHUINavigationBar class] forClassName:@"UINavigationBar"];
    [unarchiver setClass:[UIViewController class] forClassName:NSStringFromClass([navigationController.topViewController class])];
    return unarchiver;
})()) decodeObjectForKey:@"root"] initWithRootViewController:navigationController.topViewController];
```

Answer (score 0):

For a static view (no animation at all), I use the default iOS [setBackgroundImage](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html)

But when I have a view that's animated (resize most likely), I create a custom UIImageView and add it to the navigationBar so that I have more flexibility over it

The thing is if you just add it, it will get on top of the buttons and the titleView, so I manually save a copy of most of subviews, remove them from parent view, add my imageView and than add all the subviews back

This works for me

```
    UIImageView *navBackground = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationBackgroundSample.jpg"]];
    UIView *tempTitleView = [[self.navigationBar.subviews objectAtIndex:1] autorelease];
    [[self.navigationBar.subviews objectAtIndex:1] removeFromSuperview];
    [self.navigationBar addSubview:navBackground];
    [self.navigationBar addSubview:tempTitleView];
    self.navigationBar.clipsToBounds = YES;
    [navBackground release];
```

In this case, I don't have buttons and I found out that my titleView is at index 1, if you have buttons, they should be around somewhere in the subviews array of navigationBar

I don't know what's at index 0, I don't know if this can work around the case you have text title neither...