# How can I get a 'matte' color on a UINavigationBar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar, uicolor

How can I get a matte color on a UINavigationBar instead of the shiny look?

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no built-in way to do this. Using `tintColor` will always get you the default "shiny" look. The alternative is to draw the bar yourself, using the technique described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704558/custom-uinavigationbar-background), to get the look you want.

Comment: FWIW, it seems that the most voted and accepted answer is **not** a good idea, since it apparently (see comments there) won't work in iOS5. The UINavigationBar must be subclassed, not extended with a category that overrides `drawRect:`

Comment: Why subclass? In iOS 5 there is a method `setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:` so in your category why not do a `respondsToSelector:` check first then use the appropriate method?

Answer (score 0):

My simple way using category UINavigationBar:

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (UINavigationBarWithoutShiny)
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {}
@end
```

after this i can use just background color of UINavigationBar view:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```