# Assign custom navigation bar to UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Custom UINavigationBar Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704558/custom-uinavigationbar-background)

I am creating my uinavigation controller programatically in the application delegate. I have a class that subclasses UINavigationBar and would like to assign that as the controller's navigation bar. In IB, I would just select the controller, its bar and change the class from the default to my custom class. However I don't know how to do this in code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just started typing out a detailed reply when I remembered that I used my custom navigation controller from [this](http://idevrecipes.com/2011/01/12/how-do-iphone-apps-instagramreederdailybooth-implement-custom-navigationbar-with-variable-width-back-buttons/) post

Guess it is exactly what you're looking for as well.

Comment: You got accepted but I recon that your answer is actually wrong since in your example, the UINavigationController is not created programmatically but in Interface Builder.

Comment: answer is wrong. It is not done programmatically

Comment: This is doing it in IB, not programatically...