# clear background image for navigationbar IOS 5 and 4

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I am going to have different background image for navigation bar.(e.g.:when it is pushed)

i use this code

```
if([self respondsToSelector: @selector( presentingViewController)]){            
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sectionImage_iphone.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];        
    }else{
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer.contents removeFromSuperlayer];
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer.contents = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"sectionImage_iphone.png"].CGImage;
  }
```

If i call it again does the background image is replaced or stacked? if stacked, how to remove it?(for ios 4 and 5)

Thank You

Comment: This Post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704558/custom-uinavigationbar-background
Might help you

Comment: that one is only used once right? i already can make background image for navigation bar. What i want to do is to replace it.