# How do I customize the navigation bar on the iPhone in Xcode ?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationbar

I have the following code-snippets :

1.)

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:myImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Where would I put that ?

or 2.)

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (BackgroundImage)
//This overridden implementation will patch up the NavBar with a custom Image instead of the title
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
     UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"NavigationBar.png"];
     [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}
@end
```

Where would I put that ?

I have tried adding a navigation bar to my viewcontroller but I don't exactly know where to put these pieces of code.

Comment: you can also ask what would you need to customize, for say changing entire navigation color/bar/titleImage... etc.

Comment: Question seems like a duplicate, you can refer following thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704558/custom-uinavigationbar-background

Answer (score 1):

Snippet 1 is iOS 5.0 only. You'd put that somewhere before your navigation bar is created so possibly in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`. Take a look here for more information:

- http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIAppearance

Snippet 2 is what you used to have to do before iOS 5.0. That's a category on `UINavigationBar`. I've not actually seen overriding `drawRect:` in a category before but it does appear that it works. Just create a category within your project on `UINavigationBar` and add that code. So something like:

`UINavigationBar+MyCategory.h`:

```
@interface UINavigationBar (MyCategory)
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect;
@end
```

`UINavigationBar+MyCategory.m`:

```
#import "UINavigationBar+MyCategory.h"

@implementation UINavigationBar (MyCategory)
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
     UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"NavigationBar.png"];
     [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}
@end
```

Comment: No need to put `drawRect` into the `.h` file. It is not public and should not be called directly.

Comment: I am pretty new to objective-c, and unfortunately I happen to have never used a category...so basically I have to create a new class of UINavigationBar called `UINavigationBar+MyCategory.h` ?

Comment: I suggest you go and read about what an Objective-C category is (try Wikipedia or Cocoa Dev Central) and then it should become clear. What I've shown is the 2 *files* to create and then add them to your project.

Comment: Ok thank you. Is it OK if I just subclass UINavigationBar and tell my Navbar in storyboard to be of this class ... Without making categories ? What are the upsides/downsides of my approach ?

Comment: You could do that as well, yes.