# ios : how to remove the white space bar above navigation bar?

Tags: iphone, navigation, space

For Customing navigation bar, I want set the background image and custom the left button and right button.so I instance it with code without .xib. but there is a white space bar above navigation bar.

here is my code :

```
-(void) createNavBar:(NSMutableArray *)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary *)options
{
    if (!navBar)
    {
        navBarController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] init] autorelease];
        navBarController.navigationBar.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40);
        [navBarController.navigationBar  setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"www/images/header_bg@2x.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
        [[[self webView] superview] addSubview: navBarController.navigationBar];
    }
}
```

run and build, find there is a white space bar above navigation bar.
here is a Screenshot：
[image]

How can remove the space bar between the title bar and the blue navigation bar?
Thanks for your guide.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704558/custom-uinavigationbar-background

Comment: try by using only navigation bar instead of navigationController.. if u r not using navicationController

Comment: It's Carrier, time and battery information space !

Answer (score 0):

In Xib check your view and webView `Y` and `height`

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

insert `[self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer setMasksToBounds:NO];` in viewDidLoad