# Custom Table view headers

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

How can I customize the navigation bar of a table view?
An example, not limited to, would be Google Drive's black bar.
Additionally, other apps have navigation bars with images!
What other properties can I customize and HOW?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a repeat question, and a commonly asked/answered question also:

[Custom UINavigationBar Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704558/custom-uinavigationbar-background)

Comment: Are there any presets to creating like a BLACK header for navigation bar? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:153.0f/255.0f green:153.0f/255.0f blue: alpha:1]];
```