# UINavigationBar with shaped background

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to make a custom UINavigationBar, but the problem is that my background image has a curve in it, and its little bit larger than default navigation bar. When I try to set background image and change navigation bar size, its just scales image as a rectangle. Any ideas?

Bar: 
[image: navigation bar background]

Comment: I haven't tried this but maybe you could make the navigation bar background transparent, and draw this image on the main UIWindow?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom UINavigationBar Background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704558/custom-uinavigationbar-background)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override

```
- (CGSize) sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size  {
  return CGSizeMake(custom_width, custom_height);
}
```

in order to return the size for your custom navigation bar.

Note that if you use a height that is not a multiple of 4, it will cause trouble if you hide and then show the navigation bar at any point (it gets shifted by 1 pixel from the top)