# how can I make three paging views with a custom nav bar in swift

Tags: ios, swift

[Final Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzpAc.gif)

I'm trying to make this, three paging views in one with a custom nav bar with icons that will scale when its view is brought up. What is the best way to make the three views, like snapchat's, and how can I relate them to the icons in the nav bar to them? I know that I'll use collection view inside those views with supplementary cells.

I tried to make a Collection View with 3 cells moving horizontally to make the views but I cant relate the icons in the nav bar.

By the way, is it possible to make the navbar triangular like in the GIF?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question but will try to give you pointers for each of the features you are requesting.

To handle the paging views similar to snapchat with relative icons check out [SLPagingView](https://github.com/StefanLage/SLPagingViewSwift). This is a great place for you to get started. You'll need to add in some more code for the scaling but should be trivial.

In order to create a navigation bar similar to what you want you'll need to subclass `UINavigationBar` and override `sizeThatFits` and set a `backgroundImage`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25569210/uinavigationcontroller-with-custom-shape-navigation-bar) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19878288/ios-custom-shape-navigation-bar) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14281822/uinavigationbar-with-shaped-background).

Comment: I'm trying to use **SLPagingView** but whener I use a collection view as a controller I get `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter'`